# Vba code for 1 field from access form to excel

Tags: ms-access, vba

What is the simplest VBA code I could put in an access form button that will export a field value to a specified cell in excel?

Answer (score 1):

Please do search before submitting a question in StackOverflow. There a multiple answers to this question and you did not include sufficient background too.
Is your Excel open?
Is your Excel even created?
I
I'll attach the code to create a new instance of Excel,  and write text to a specific cell.

```
Private Sub Button_Click()
Dim objExcel As Excel.Application
Dim objSheet As Excel.Workbook

Set objExcel = New Excel.Application
Set objSheet = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\MyExcelfile.xlsx")

objExcel.Range("C6").Value = "Some text to write here"
objExcel.Range("D7").Value = me.textboxSomething.value

objSheet.save
Set objSheet = Nothing
objExcel.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
End sub
```

You have to deal with error handling in case of error.
Do note you have to add "Microsoft Excel 1#.0 Object library" reference, in your access vba editor, under tools menu.